# why do we need the argument labels during the function call in swift

Tags: swift

I have just started reading Learn Essentials of Swift

```
func greet(name: String, day: String) -> String {
   return "Hello \(name), today is \(day)."
}
```

syntax to call

```
  greet("Anna",day : "Tuesday")
```

My Questions:

1. What is the real need of sending the name of the parameter
2. Will it match the name before copying the value in the function
3. If it matches the names , if i interchange values while i call the  function , below code fails

   ```
    func greet(name: String, day: String,time: String) -> String
    {
       return "Hello \(name), today is \(day), \(time)."
    }  
   greet("Anna", time: "one forty",day: "Tuesday")
   ```

How does the function parameter mechanism work internally ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter

Comment: Internally, the compiler generates a unique name for the function. See [name mangling](https://www.apteligent.com/developer-resources/the-complete-guide-to-function-mangling-in-ios/)

Answer (score 1):

As you find in the link in the comment, there are some advantages of named parameters: They make the code clearer.

However, in Objective-C there has been named parameters from the very beginning. To be more honest, they have been akin of named parameters, because the names are part of the method name (selector). In your example, the method in Objective-C would be: `greetName:day:`. This is different from `greetName:day:time:`. At least Swift needs the capability to handle that.

> What is the real need of sending the name of the parameter

Names parameters make the code more readable. There can be many methods with different parameter names.

> Will it match the name before copying the value in the function

Yes. It builds the function name from the argument names in the call and try to match it with the parameter names of a potential method.

> If it matches the names , if i interchange values while i call the function , below code fails

In Objective-C and Swift the order of the named parameters is important. You can have two different methods with interchanged names. `greetName:day:time:` is different to `greetName:time:day:`.